# Taylor Expansion of inverse of a matrix (need verification that this is completely wrong)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, taylor-expansion

I am reading machine learning paper and came across something which seems really wrong.

"Let $H_j^{-1} = \Sigma_{i=0}^j(1-H)^i $, first $j$ terms in the Taylor expansion of $H^{-1}$. From validity of the Taylor expansion $H_j^{-1} \rightarrow H^{-1}$." (Not an exact quotation but something similar)

$H$ is supposed to be Hessian matrix of convex function so it is positive definite.

Well I've not really heard of Talyor expansion of a matrix let alone inverse of it (except some special cases) and just by multiplying $H_j^{-1}$ by $H$, it is pretty clear that $HH_j^{-1}$ won't converge to identity matrix except for very special cases. And H can have as small eigenvalue as we want (Not sure if it makes much difference)

So my question is

1. Am I correct in thinking things in this quote is wrong
2. Would it be typo (ie small fix that it would make similar statement work) or some special case where this sort of method would work? (I know this part is ambiguous but I can't think of rigorous way of putting it)

Comment: Try searching "Neumann series" if you want. That's the subject explained by Ted Shifrin in the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not completely wrong. The missing hypothesis that's needed for the series to converge is that $\|I-H\|<1$ (say the operator norm). Positive definiteness of $H$ is not sufficient, but, together with small (positive) eigenvalues, this will hold.

It's easier to think of the usual geometric series expansion
$$(1-x)^{-1} = \frac1{1-x} = 1+x+x^2+ \dots = \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k, \quad |x|<1.$$
It works just fine when $x$ is a matrix $A$ with norm less than $1$. (This is the usual fact that absolute convergence in a normed linear space implies convergence, together with the bound $\|A^k\|\le \|A\|^k$.) That is, we have
$$(I-A)^{-1} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty A^k, \quad \|A\|<1.$$
Now, just substitute $A=I-H$.